# Easiest way to add TabBar to an existing application

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

Can someone advise if there is a quick way to convert an existing iPhone app to a tab bar app?
I can create a new storyboard using TabBar controller, however I think there must be a way to add UITabBar to an existing controller.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

In XCode, select the existing controller in your storyboard, then from the main menu, select Editor, then Embed In->Tab Bar Controller.